# Please make blockquotes more visually distinct from code blocks on SO

Tags: feature-request, code-block, blockquote, visibility

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Improving Blockquote style](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85892/improving-blockquote-style)

This is a small request only, and easy to do. :)

Currently blockquotes and code blocks are rendered as virtually indistinguishable gray areas.

This makes it especially difficult to create/read an answer that goes into several sub-questions the OP asked by quoting and answering them one after the other with code samples.

Other SE sites (like German.SE) have a distinctive styling for blockquotes, I'd like to see that visual clue on SO as well.